# wordpress - if bbpress show the_content()

Tags: php, wordpress

this is how i call my contents in wordpress:

```
<?php
    if ( is_singular() ) {
    the_content();
    } else {
    the_excerpt();
    }
?>
```

but with this i can't call bbpress too because bbpress doesn't support `the_excerpt()`. now i want add another `if else` or something like that to call bbpress content.

```
<?php
    if ( is_singular() ) {
    the_content();
    } else {
    the_excerpt();
    }
    ifelse ( is_bbpress() ) {
    the_content();
    }
?>
```

i know the above code is wrong, that's why i'm asking this question! :)

any help will be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is this what you are looking for ?

```
<?php if ( is_singular() || is_bbPress() ) {
         the_content();
      } else {
         the_excerpt();
} ?>
```

Answer (score 0):

i find it here:

```
<?php
    if ( is_singular() ) {
    the_content();
    }
    elseif ( is_bbpress() ) {
    the_content();
    }
    else {
    the_excerpt();
    }
?>
```